# Passing default value to AngularJS service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controller

I have this config:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('Data', function () {
   return { message: "I'm data from a service" };
});

function FirstCtrl($scope, Data) {
   $scope.data = Data;
}

function SecondCtrl($scope, Data) {
   $scope.data = Data;
}
```

Everything works fine with a hardcoded Data.message, but how can I pass a value to the Data.message through the template? I want to avoid using extra http requests.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate on what you mean by "passing a value to the Data message throughout the template"?

Comment: Something like ng-init="message = {{ data_from_server}}" .

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it through the attribute as follows.

```
ng-init="data.message='My message from template'"
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work, it passes it to the controller instead of the service(I need it to be available in both controllers).